# Can rails on the ground or blimps in the air be positioned to collect lightning?

Tags: energy, electricity, energy-conservation, lightning, weather

This question was inspired by Ben Franklin key on a kite string. There's A Place On Earth That Experiences 1.2 Million Lighting Strikes A Year. In a small area of northwestern Venezuela, where the Catatumbo River meets Lake Maracaibo, it called the Catatumbo lightning. Could this lightning be collected by a net of some type? Could the lightning be directly converted into kinetic energy through big electromagnets built to handle to largest strike to a big spinning disk and then collected after the storm?

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvesting_lightning_energy

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31254/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19929/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/20467/2451 and links therein. More on [lightning as energy source](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+[lightning]+energy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could, but the problem is not the collection but the storage, [quote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvesting_lightning_energy):

*"the ever-changing energy involved in each lightning bolt renders lightning power harvesting from ground based rods impractical – too high, it will damage the storage, too low and it may not work."*

There have been several attempts to harvest the energy of a lightning, but they all failed (see the link above).

Comment: question revised

Comment: Plus its a very small percentage of the energy we produce through the means we have. Even if you collect it all. There's another question on that in this site